# Cloud function firestore data to model

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I has the following codes in my typescript:

```
    let user = new User();
    let exist = await db.collection('Users').where('UserId', '==', request.body.UserId)
                                             .where('CompanyId', '==', request.body.CompanyId)
                                             .limit(1)
                                             .get()

    if (exist.docs.length <= 0)
    {
        response.send(user);
    }
    else
    {
        response.send(exist.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
    }
}
```

The following is the result return from firestore query:

```
{
    "Email": "abc@gmail.com",
    "CustomerId": "CC",
    "CustomerName": "Tester",
    "CompanyId": "SG01",
    "UserId": "1234",
}
```

However, I just want to map CompanyId, CustomerId, CustomerName to User model and return User model to front-end instead of the entire document.

```
export class User {
    CompanyId: string = "";
    CustomerId: string = "";
    CustomerName: string = "";  
}
```

May i know how can I do it?

Comment: Could you edit the question to be more specific about the problem you're running into?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how to map my doc.data into a customized model instead of just return the entire doc.data to my UI

Comment: Since we can't see what your doc.data contains, and we don't know which fields should map to the class, there's not much we can do to help.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward to copy the relevant properties from doc.data into a new User object.  What part of that is confusing, to make sure I'm not misunderstanding the issue?

Comment: I am new to typescript. Appreciate if anyone can provide sample how to assign property from doc.data to a class.